# Using Vue.js (v2) to handle a table of forms

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I've been working with an package that uses vue to handle a table that has small forms to submit a delete request. I am using Vue to prevent the forms submission then I have it preventing the submitting of the form and just submit an ajax request then remove the `<td></td>` that contains the form.

#### Question

The form is submitting and Vue is not preventing the submission. It's not sending the AJax request and I have no warnings or errors appearing with Vue. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the page or with the scripting (from what I can see)

Why might this not work?

#### Vue Code:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#vue-form-wrapper",
    data: {
        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
        _method: 'DELETE',
        response: ''
    },
    methods: {
        makeRequest: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            request(e.target.action, this.$data, function (responseArea) {
                if (responseArea.classList.contains('alert')) {
                    responseArea.className += 'alert-success ';
                    responseArea.className = responseArea.className.replace(/\balert-.*\s/g, ' alert-success');
                    $(e.parent).parent().parent().parent().remove();
                }
            }, function (responseArea) {
                if (responseArea.classList.contains('alert')) {
                    responseArea.className += 'alert-warning ';
                    responseArea.className = responseArea.className.replace(/\balert-.*\s/g, ' alert-warning');
                }
            }, function (responseArea) {
                if (responseArea.classList.contains('alert')) {
                    responseArea.className += 'alert-danger ';
                    responseArea.className = responseArea.className.replace(/\balert-.*\s/g, ' alert-danger');
                }
            });
            form = e.target;
        },
        close: function (e) {
            this.response = '';
        }
    }
});
```

#### Request function (for ajax)

```
function request(url, data, success, fail, nochange) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
    xmlhttp.open("{{$type}}", url);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            vm.$data.response = response.message;
            var respArea = document.getElementById('response');
            if (!respArea.classList.contains('alert)')) {
                respArea.className = 'alert ';
            }
            switch (response.code) {
                case 200:
                case 202:
                    success(respArea);
                    break;
                case 205:
                    nochange(respArea);
                    break;
                default:
                    fail(respArea);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

#### My Form

```
<div class="panel-body" id="vue-form-wrapper">
   <div id="response" v-show="response">
      {{ response }}
      <div class="close" v-on="click:close">&times;</div>
   </div>
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <th>uuid</th>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>email</th>
         <th style="width:40px">Edit</th>
         <th style="width:54px">Delete</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <i>No data here</i>
            </td>
            <td>
               asfdadsf
            </td>
            <td>
               austinkregel@afsdaf
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="font-size:24px;">
               <a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/user/manage/105">
               <i class=" fa fa-edit "></i>
               </a>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="text-align:right;float:right; font-size:24px;padding-right:10px;">
                  <form action="http://hidden.dev/warden/api/v1.0/user/105"
                     method='post' @submit.prevent="makeRequest">
                     <input type="submit" value="Text">
                  </form>
               </span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               e35015f4-82c1-4689-989b-de5f6c2d87f6
            </td>
            <td>
               Random
            </td>
            <td>
               guy@random.co
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="font-size:24px;">
               <a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/user/manage/106">
               <i class=" fa fa-edit "></i>
               </a>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="text-align:right;float:right; font-size:24px;padding-right:10px;">
                  <form action="http://hidden.dev/warden/api/v1.0/user/106"
                     method='post' @submit.prevent="makeRequest">
                     <input type="submit" value="Text">
                  </form>
               </span>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               861dc4a3-91a2-42b1-9548-67ba067498ee
            </td>
            <td>
               sadfasdf
            </td>
            <td>
               austinksadfsdfaregel@gmail.com
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="font-size:24px;">
               <a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/user/manage/107">
               <i class=" fa fa-edit "></i>
               </a>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <span style="text-align:right;float:right; font-size:24px;padding-right:10px;">
                  <form action="http://hidden.dev/warden/api/v1.0/user/107"
                     method='post' @submit.prevent="makeRequest">
                     <input type="submit" value="Text">
                  </form>
               </span>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div class="text-center">
      <ul class="pagination">
         <li><a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/users/manage/?page=2" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/users/manage/?page=1">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://hidden.dev/warden/users/manage/?page=2">2</a></li>
         <li class="active"><span>3</span></li>
         <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, what do you mean by "it's not submitting"? I see a POST request being initiated when I hit one of the buttons.

Comment: I should re-word that, it is submitting; however, it is not  preventing the submission and sending the Ajax request. Which it should be preventing the submission and the sending the Ajax.

Comment: @nick I did reword that for you.

Comment: I didn't change a dang thing, and now it's working again... I don't know what's happening right now.

Comment: Haha, glad it works though. I couldn't find anything wrong with your code :P

Comment: Thank you for your time anyway! :D